# SQL with SubSelect refering to same Table as Inital load is slow

Tags: sql, db2, odbc

i DISTINCT load multiple Tables together:

```
Simple DISTINCT SELECT Table1.Val1, Table2.Val2, Table1.Val3,... 
FROM Table1/2/3 
WHERE Table2.KEYVAL = TABLE1.KEYVAL
AND TABLE3.KEYVAL = TABLE2.KEYVAL
some WHERE's on Table 1,2,3
```

I also have some Subselects with a 4th Table in my Main Select Statement which work fast and fine.

Now i want to calculate the SUM of a Value in Table3 (let's call it weight).
Table3 Result has Multiple Rows (Sub-ID's) but share the Same KEY.

How can i accomplish that?

if i put a SubSelect in my Main Select:

```
(SELECT Sum(weight) 
FROM Table3
WHERE Table3.KEYVAL = Table1.KEYVAL
) as Wheight
```

it get's ugly slow.

How can i (or does sql) differ between (Main)Table3.weight and (SubSelect)Table3.weight when i want to use a LeftJoin for that Weight?

Sum(weight) in Main Select does not work directly, i think because of not being DISTINCT?

Comment: Thanks Tom for formatting!

Comment: i've put that SQL in a PowerShell Script .. and loaded the 4th Table as Hashtable, so that i can glue them toghether. I have not found an other fast way.. so far...`SELECT Key, Sum(Value) 
FROM Table4 
GROUP BY Key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use the Group by function in your subquery.

For instance:

```
Select a.*, b.*
  from mytable as a
  join (select keyval, sum(weight) from my_second_table group by keyval) as b  
    on a.keyval = b.keyval
```